# Is it possible to cache data in python kafka producer by itself?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm a newbie in Kafka. My task is to send real-time data from Raspberry to a Kafka topic on another server.
I created a Kafka producer instance, connected it to the right topic, and everything works.

The problem is that due to an unstable Internet connection, data may not be delivered.
I would like that until the connection is restored, my data is not lost and cached.

Is it possible to make it by Kafka producer instance or do I need to make the cache system by myself?

In the python Kafka producer [documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html), I found a config parameter called "buffer_memory" which takes a value of bytes that can be cached by the producer if there is no response from the Kafka server.
I want to understand:

- Is it caching on disk or RAM?
- Is it correct to use this parameter in my case? I want to cache as much data as possible.

What is the best practice in my case?

**UPD:**
I tried to simulate the loss of an Internet connection by shutting down the cluster locally. All I get is
KafkaTimeoutError: Batch for TopicPartition(topic='test_local', partition=2) containing 1 record(s) expired: 30 seconds have passed since the last append.

It looks like the buffering option is responsible for buffering the collected batch for sending, and not buffering the data as I need.
Because if I restart the cluster my data is not delivered to the topic.

Comment: You might want to look at this instead https://github.com/rh-marketingops/fluvii#fluviitableapp-caching

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Can you briefly explain what this library does? I'm trying to read the documentation and it seems that writing to the database occurs on the consumer side. Since the FluviiTableApp class does not have send methods. I would be glad for an explanation, I'm trying to figure it out and I will be glad for any help.

Comment: I think it'd be best to start at the official Kafka Streams docs, as that library is based on it, but Kafka Streams wraps producer and consumer API (needs to start with consuming existing topic data), but it can execute stateful aggregates to create tables/caches on-disk or in memory... In any case, maybe I misunderstood the problem. Kafka producers will buffer, by default, but you could use Python's own Queue class or sqlite table to front a KafkaProducer rather than immediately try to send data on a flaky network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a receiver or consumer is disconnected from the internet in Kafka, the Kafka cache functionality will continue to function normally as long as the receiver has previously fetched the data and stored it in its local cache.

In Kafka, the cache data is stored locally on the consumer's system. When a consumer fetches data from Kafka, it stores the data in its local cache, which is typically implemented as an in-memory data store or a local database. The data is stored in a format that is optimized for fast access and querying.

In Kafka, the cache size determines the amount of memory allocated for the local cache, and the retention policy determines how long the data remains in the cache before it is discarded

To increase the cache size and retention policy, you can modify the following properties in the consumer configuration:

**cache.max.bytes.buffering**: This property specifies the maximum amount of memory allocated for the local cache. Increasing this value will allow the cache to store more messages.

**state.cleanup.delay.ms**: This property specifies the time duration after which the data in the cache is discarded. Increasing this value will allow the cache to retain data for a longer duration

Additionally, Kafka also provides options to persist the cache data to disk or a remote database for long-term storage and durability

Comment: Am I right that configs cache.max.bytes.buffering and state.cleanup.delay.ms use for configurate consumer? Can I do this with producer? In my case I need caching data when I send message in my producer if message not sended. Thanks for answer!